# How to echo foreach array with variables on the same table row?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I echo an array with the first name and last name on the same table row and city and state on the same table row?

```
while(!empty($userphoto))
{       
//output images     
foreach(array($userphoto, $firstName, $lastName, $age, $email, $city, $state) as  $items)
{
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($items as $key=>$item)
    {
        echo "<td><font size =\"2\" >$item</td>";

        //output only four of them
        if($key==4)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: With only 4 variables it is probably easier to just echo them manually instead of generating an array, looping, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with an array and foreach loop, you could do it like this:

```
while(!empty($userphoto)) {
    $items = array($firstName, $lastName, $city, $state);
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($items as $key=>$item) {
        echo "<td>$item</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

But if it was me, I would use @jerron's suggestion:

```
while(!empty($userphoto)) {   
    echo "<tr><td>$firstName</td><td>$lastName</td><td>$city</td><td>$state</td></tr>";
}
```

I hope this helps!
Bud

Answer (score 0):

To restrict to only the first 4 items:

```
$count = 0;
while(!empty($userphoto) && $count < 4)
{
echo "<tr><td>" . $firstName . "</td><td>" . $lastName . "</td><td>" . $city . "</td><td>" . $state . "</td></tr>";
$count++;
}
```

If you're restricting to 4 records as opposed to four fields then you need to check in the outer loop, not the inner one. You don't really need the nested loop here - in [data management](http://www.northdevonitservices.co.uk) it's best to keep things simple.